# How do I add to a project with JSF 3.0 an embedded tomcat server 10.1.5 that runs from a main

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsf

I have to make a java web project with JSF 3.0, java 17, CDI 2.0 and run from a main running an embedded tomcat 10.1.5 server, but I have not succeeded because I have found very little information on how to do it, someone please Can you help me by telling me how to do it and that it works correctly? (no spring boot)

I tried an old example of an embedded tomcat 9.0.0.M6 made for JSP but trying to adapt it for JSF didn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Some caveats first:

- this uses Java 19, and JSF 4 (different from the request in the question).
- but it does use Tomcat 10.1 (matching the question).
- it places the web files in a directory external to the application (see below). This may be a **bad approach**, but I have not found a good way to reference the web files when they are located in the built JAR, in `/resources`.
- this is a bare-bones (minimal) set-up.

You can modify the `pom.xml` - I have not tried your specific target versions.

I have also only verified this with a basic "hello world" style Faces page.

---

The `pom.xml` dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Structure for `myDocBase` - the external location of all web files:

```
myDocBase
|
|-- META-INF
|   |
|   |-- beans.xml  (empty file)
|
|-- WEB-INF
|   |
|   |-- faces-config.xml
|   |-- web.xml
|
|-- hello.xhtml
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
    version="6.0"
>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have not tried this, but I expect you could declare the servlet programmatically - something like:

```java
Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "facesServlet", "jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet");
ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("*.xhtml", "facesServlet");
```

`faces-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0"
>
    <!-- Put any faces config here. -->
</faces-config>
```

---

The Faces file `hello.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
      xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Enter your name" required="true" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{hello.name}" />
            <h:message for="name" />
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Say hello" action="#{hello.createMessage}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <br />
            #{hello.message}
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

---

The `Faces.java` bean:

```java
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Hello {

    private String name;
    private String message;

    public void createMessage() {
        message = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

---

The Tomcat launcher with the `main` method:

```java
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/resources/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        Connector conn = new Connector();
        conn.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.setConnector(conn);

        tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(".");
        tomcat.setSilent(false);

        Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

}
```

---

At the command line, assuming all the supporting JARs are in a `lib` directory; and (as noted above) the `myDocBase` directory is in the same parent directory as the JAR file:

```
java -cp lib/*;MyEmbeddedJsfDemo.jar org.me.App
```

Start-up log:

```
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:45 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:45 P.M. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:45 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:45 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:45 P.M. org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:46 P.M. org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:46 P.M. org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener onStartup
INFO: WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:46 P.M. org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 4.0.3 (Final)
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:47 P.M. org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:47 P.M. org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.TomcatContainer initialize
INFO: WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:47 P.M. com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 4.0.2 for context ''
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:47 P.M. com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:47 P.M. org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.0.Final
Apr 29, 2023 5:22:48 P.M. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```